# Make achievement with over 10,000 steps using Google Play Game Api

Tags: google-play-services

At the Google I/O developer conference Google released a new game service one of the parts of it was achievement support. I would like to make a achievement that is get one million coins but the incremental achievement on supports achievement that have less then 10,000 steps see [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements#incremental_achievements). Is there anyway to get around this? How can I make an achievement like get a million coins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question. Basically what I'm doing is just keep track of it locally, then unlocking it all at once when they reach the goal. Not ideal but it works. 
I suppose that you could also increment it by say 1/10 of the actual value (or in your case 1M/10000) so that when you reach the peak, it is unlocked when the user has earned the one million points or coins etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly using Google Play Games Service.

However, the number of steps is not displayed to the player in the default UI.
User can only see the percent value on it.

A good approach for you would be to save the total number of coins in an external save (Google Cloud Save?) and report an increment to your GamesClient only when a new percent is reached.

This solution will also minimize the API calls and help you manage your [daily quota](https://developers.google.com/games/services/bestpractices).